# Image not showing up HTML5 Canvas (multiple images) with the drawImage function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Everyone! I am making a school project with the `HTML5` canvas and upon adding a second image (with the `drawImage` function), it won't show up. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Game</title>
</head>

<body> <canvas id="gC" width="1500" height="1000"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.querySelector("#gC");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var team1 = new Image();
    var bT = new Image();
    var t1_x = 250;
    var t1_y = 250;
    var bT_x = 50;
    var bT_y = 350;
    canvas.height = 1000;
    canvas.width = 1500;
    team1.xPos = 250;
    team1.yPos = 250;
    team1.src = "../game/team1.png";
    bT.src = "../game/bT.png";
    dE();

    function team1AI() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.height, ctx.canvas.width);
        ctx.drawImage(team1, t1_x, t1_y);
        t1_x++;
    }
    setInterval(team1AI, 10);

    function dE() {
        ctx.drawImage(team1, t1_x, t1_y);
        ctx.drawImage(bT, bT_x, bT_y);
    }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #gC {
        position: relative;
        left: 16vw;
        top: 9vh;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    body {
        background-image: url('bg.jpeg') !important;
    }
    </style>
```

I need this fixed A.S.A.P! Please, everyone. I need to get a good grade on this.

Thanks so much,
Ben A.K.A BlackSky!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure this is what you exactly want but, here you go ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Game</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #gC {
        position: relative;
        left: 16vw;
        top: 9vh;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
        background-image: url('bg.jpeg') !important;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body> <canvas id="gC" width="1500" height="1000"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.querySelector("#gC");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var team1 = new Image();
    var bT = new Image();
    var t1_x = 250;
    var t1_y = 250;
    var bT_x = 50;
    var bT_y = 350;
    var interval;
    var seconds = 0;
    team1.src = "https://www.dreamteamfc.com/g/img/dream-team-logo.png";
    bT.src = "https://team.valvoline.com/sites/all/themes/v2/img/sidebarnav/teamv_hover.png";

    function team1AI() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
        ctx.drawImage(bT, bT_x, bT_y);
        ctx.drawImage(team1, t1_x, t1_y);
        t1_x++;
        seconds++;
        interval = requestAnimationFrame(team1AI);
    }
    setInterval(function() {
        if (seconds === 450) cancelAnimationFrame(interval);
    }, 1000 / 60);
    team1AI();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That worked! But first, what does requestAnimationFrame(team1AI); do?

Comment: Also, how do I stop it??

Comment: @CyberakaTHEGAMERCraft [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) is an alternative for `setInterval() / setTimeout()`, mostly used in canvas animation and to stop it, use [`cancelAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame)

Comment: @CyberakaTHEGAMERCraft also, if the answer was helpful to you then, don't forget to accept and upvote it :-)

Comment: If you don't mind, can you write the code out using the cancelAnimationFrame();

Comment: @CyberakaTHEGAMERCraft when you wanna stop it?

Comment: After about 7.5 seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138458/discussion-between-cyber-aka-thegamer-craft-and-siam).